# Integrate $\int _{(V)}(x+y+z)\,dx\, dy\, dz $

Tags: integration

Is this integral $\int _{(V)}(x+y+z)\,dx \,dy \,dz  $ equal to $0$?
where $(V)=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\leq  R^2\}$; $R$ is a set
I calculated it many times but it always gives $0.$

Comment: That integral *is* $0$, so you calculated correctly.

Comment: It is $0$ because it's an integral of an odd function over a region that is symmetric about the origin.